# Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by UnconnectedImages. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My question is nothing new here - I have checked few similar ones but none of them gave me clear answer.

After first render of certain component I receive error as above. It does not happen on next renders.
Now code:

```
  const handlePointerMove = useCallback(
    debounce(e => {
      const mouse = e.pageY;
      const height = window.innerHeight;

      if (mouse >= 0.8 * height) {
        fetchImages(subject);
      }
    }, 300),
    [fetchImages]
  );
```

The above is probably error 'author' but look at the rest. The above one is written as just first command in the component (simplified for clearer).

The rest is as follows( it is one useEffect with content of three fns )

```
  useEffect(() => {
  
    window.addEventListener("pointermove", handlePointerMove)
 window.addEventListener( "click",debounce(e => {xxxxxxx)
window.addEventListener( "click",debounce(e => {yyyyyyyy)
  },[]);
```

My first idea it was to remove handlePointerMove from its position and inline it in useEffect, but it gave no effect(I suspected that it can not be told for sure which happens first  const handlePointerMove will be created or component mounted. But thi si not the case obviously.
If not that - what?

Comment: Not sure about this one, but maybe try unsubscribing from the event listener when the component unmounts?

Comment: Hi, The reason was that I tried to unsubscribe handler twice!  It was in part of code I have not quoted here. Surprisingly,  it had not thrown error clearly about it, but the one I have quoted.

Comment: Haha OK, glad it's solved!